# java.lang.RuntimeException: Evaluation of expression failed due to reflection errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration.

I have this problem in the JSP

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Evaluation of expression [${userItem.deviceBody.key}] failed due to reflection errors.

But everything is fine in my Junit test:

```
for (User user : deviceBodies) {
    assertNotNull (user.getDeviceBody());
    assertNotNull (user.getDeviceBody().getKey());
}
```

Here the full error:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Evaluation of expression [${userItem.deviceBody.key}] failed due to reflection errors.
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.support.TagAttributeUtils.contextSpecificEvaluate(TagAttributeUtils.java:94)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.ColumnTag.evaluateValueFromExpression(ColumnTag.java:415)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.ColumnTag.doEndTag(ColumnTag.java:441)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag6(__listcbbody.java:575)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag5(__listcbbody.java:503)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag4(__listcbbody.java:452)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag1(__listcbbody.java:309)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jspService(__listcbbody.java:225)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:478)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:480)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:347)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:204)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._template.__template._jsp__tag2(__template.java:365)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._template.__template._jspService(__template.java:247)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:272)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.export.ExcelExportFilter.doFilter(ExcelExportFilter.java:39)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.EventDispatcherFilter.doFilter(EventDispatcherFilter.java:38)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.RequestUrlFilter.doFilter(RequestUrlFilter.java:31)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.env.ecolabel.support.context.EcolabelSecurityFilter.doFilter(EcolabelSecurityFilter.java:82)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:216)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.support.TagAttributeUtils.contextSpecificEvaluate(TagAttributeUtils.java:92)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.ColumnTag.evaluateValueFromExpression(ColumnTag.java:415)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.ColumnTag.doEndTag(ColumnTag.java:441)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag6(__listcbbody.java:575)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag5(__listcbbody.java:503)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag4(__listcbbody.java:452)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag1(__listcbbody.java:309)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jspService(__listcbbody.java:225)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:478)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:480)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:347)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:204)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._template.__template._jsp__tag2(__template.java:365)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._template.__template._jspService(__template.java:247)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:272)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.export.ExcelExportFilter.doFilter(ExcelExportFilter.java:39)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.EventDispatcherFilter.doFilter(EventDispatcherFilter.java:38)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.RequestUrlFilter.doFilter(RequestUrlFilter.java:31)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.env.ecolabel.support.context.EcolabelSecurityFilter.doFilter(EcolabelSecurityFilter.java:82)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException
        at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.ArrayRefEvaluator.evaluateBeanType(ArrayRefEvaluator.java:252)
        at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.ArrayRefEvaluator.evaluate(ArrayRefEvaluator.java:49)
        at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.ELNode$RefExpression.evaluate(ELNode.java:494)
        at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl$ELExpression.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:188)
        at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.el.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:216)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.support.TagAttributeUtils.contextSpecificEvaluate(TagAttributeUtils.java:92)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.ColumnTag.evaluateValueFromExpression(ColumnTag.java:415)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.ColumnTag.doEndTag(ColumnTag.java:441)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag6(__listcbbody.java:575)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag5(__listcbbody.java:503)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag4(__listcbbody.java:452)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jsp__tag1(__listcbbody.java:309)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._accounts.__listcbbody._jspService(__listcbbody.java:225)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:478)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:480)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:347)
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:204)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._template.__template._jsp__tag2(__template.java:365)
        at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp._template.__template._jspService(__template.java:247)
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:573)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:272)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.taglib.datagrid.export.ExcelExportFilter.doFilter(ExcelExportFilter.java:39)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.EventDispatcherFilter.doFilter(EventDispatcherFilter.java:38)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.ergonomics.filter.RequestUrlFilter.doFilter(RequestUrlFilter.java:31)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.tdk.env.ecolabel.support.context.EcolabelSecurityFilter.doFilter(EcolabelSecurityFilter.java:82)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
```

Comment: Are your assertions disabled? (Might try it with `Assert.assertNotNull(...)` from org.​junit.​Assert).

Comment: everything is fine in the Test, even I put a System.out.println to verify

Comment: provide more information from stacktrace... it should have the real reason for error down below..